# printing first lines section ,untill getting to the first space

Tags: linux, bash

I have a list of all satellite channels in a file.
I want to get only child channels that belongs to specific child channel.
(`$i` is base channel1 in the below examples.)

Original content of the file:

```
B base channel1
C       child channel1
C       child channel2

B base channel2
C       child channel3

B base channel3 
C       child channel4
```

I want to get only:

```
child channel1
child channel2
```

I have tried:

```
cat /tmp/channel_list | grep -E -A10 '(^| )'$i'( |$)'| \
  grep -E -A10 '(^| )'$i'( |$)' | sed -n '/^B/,/^B/p' | \
  grep -v B | perl -i -pe 's/\s+\n/\n/' | sed 's/^ *//; s/ *$//; /^$/d'
```

Which produces:

```
C       child channel1
C       child channel2
C       child channel3
```

But I want this - how can I get only this?

```
child channel1
child channel2
```

Comment: Note that `cat file | grep pattern` is an **anti-pattern** that is better written as `grep pattern file`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a shell variable `$i` which contains the string `base channel1`, you could use an awk script like this:

```
awk -v channel="$i" '$0 ~ channel { f = 1; next } !NF { f = 0 } f { print $2, $3 }' file
```

When the line matches the pattern stored in the variable, the flag `f` is set and the program skips to the next line. When there are no fields (empty line), it is unset. While the flag is set, print the second and third fields.

You can avoid using `next` by rearranging the blocks, so `f` is only set after it is checked on the line that matches:

```
awk -v channel="$i" '!NF { f = 0 } f { print $2, $3 } $0 ~ channel { f = 1 }' file
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to write a shell script that accept as first argument the file path name:

```
#!/bin/bash
i="base channel1"
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
        if echo $line | grep "$i" > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
        then
                while IFS='' read -r line && [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
                        echo $line | awk '{split($0,a,"C")} END{print a[1], a[2]}' | xargs
                done
                break
        fi
done
```

Run the script as: script_name /tmp/channel_list

I get the following output:

```
    child channel1
    child channel2
```

Another possible way is:
 - with the first sed I select the block starting with the pattern and ending with the empty line
 - the second sed remove the blanck line 
 - the third remove the initiali "C  " prefix

```
 
sed -n "/^B $i/,/^\s*\$/{1d;p;}" /tmp/channel_list | sed '$ d' | sed 's/^C *//g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sed to get the content between the $i and an empty line,
then cut away the unwanted 'C'

`cat test|sed -n "/$i/{:a;n;/^\s*$/b;p;ba}"|cut -c 9-`

output:

```
child channel1
child channel2
```

Answer (score 0):

The last sed chain mentioned above worked for me:

Listing only satellite child channel channels:

`$i` is base `channel1`

```
rhn-satellite-exporter --list-channels |grep -E -A10 '(^| )'$i'( |$)'|sed -n "/B $i/,/^\s/{1d;p}"| sed '$ d' |sed 's/^C *//g'|awk '{print $1}'
```

**output:**

child channel1

child channel2